# How to show name in foreign key?

Tags: python, django

[image]

In Models:

```html
class ShopCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "tbl_ShopCategory"
        
        
class Shop(models.Model):
    id_shop = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    cover_img = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ShopCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avgscore = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

I want to show the Category name?
...........................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an **str** method to your ShopCategory model:

```
class ShopCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

    class Meta:
        db_table = "tbl_ShopCategory"
```